# React-native - Firebase onAuthStateChanged not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have not been able to persist a firebase session in my react-native application. This question is nearly identical to 
[React Native - Firebase auth persistence not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46143273/react-native-firebase-auth-persistence-not-working)
but the answer provided there has not worked for me.

Currently I log in as shown below:

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
      .catch(() => loginUserFailed(dispatch))

  };
};
```

My session is created and I have access to the user object stored on firebase.

When I Cmd+R or when I close the application and reopen it my session is gone. I have run the following in the componentWillMount() section of my app.js file:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    console.log('user is logged');
  } else {
    console.log('not logged in')
  }
});
```

Whenever I refresh the app or close it completely and reopen I get the 'not logged in' response.

I have also tried querying:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser
```

but get the same issue where it returns null

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a particular way to keep the session active that I am missing?

Comment: The credentials temp key is stored in the browser (session or cookies or both). You may have modified your browser to clear sessions upon page close? Not sure. I can even open a new tab using the same browser and will already be logged in. Hope that helps. Check your browser session/cookie settings back to default?

Comment: @ronroyston This is for a react native mobile application. I️ am creating a native application for android and iOS devices. I️ don’t think applications delete session cookies. I️ could be wrong though

Comment: Are you using the latest version of firebase.js? There was an issue that was fixed in 4.5.2 related to react-native persistence.

Comment: This looks a lot like the Udemy react-native coursework and it's the same problem I'm experiencing. The user never gets reset after reloading the app so it always displays the log out button never the login form. I have a gist here https://gist.github.com/mjstelly/42124cc52bf08b1b257e1e535fa163ad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since I posted this question but I thought I would post my solution.

As it turns out my initial set up (kind of) worked. By that I mean that onAuthStateChanged was taking some time to hear back from firebase and during that time the rest of the application loaded thinking that the user was not logged in, due to that being the default state.

I managed to get around this by moving the onAuthStateChanged logic out of the app.js and in to the initial home page in componentWillMount. which now looks like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {

    SplashScreen.hide()
    this.setState({ loading: false })

    this.props.persistedUserLoginSuccess({user, navigate})

    this.props.fetchUserData();

  } else {

    SplashScreen.hide()
    this.setState({ loading: false })

  }
});
```

Also, I managed to better the user experience by forcing the splash screen to stay up which the auth was being queried. Upon completion the splash screen was hidden and the application loaded as either a logged in application or one where the user had not yet logged in.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because you are not doing Firebase.auth().signOut() after once loggedIn. Try to signOut (for testing you can always sign out in componentWillMount function) and you will be able to see the onAuthStateChanged notification.

Comment: onAuthStateChanged will fire whenever the user is verified true or false