# React native + Firebase cloud function: Keep user loged in?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, expo

I'm working on a React-Native, Expo and Firebase project. I have built my firebase functions as cloud functions. The login, signup and register are built as a cloud function aswell. I'm using Email and Password to authenticate/signup the user.

I have used the method to store the token on the device and log the user in if it exists. However the token expires after 1h and after that my method does not work.

I have tried to use 
`firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)`
but that does not seem to work with cloud functions and returns error code: The current environmet does not support the specified persistence type.

What kind of workaround for this problem is there? Building a seperate cloud function that only refreshes the token, and in that case how do i achive that? What pros and cons is there for different solutions? Thankfull for feedback and 
thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

According to `React Native Firebase`'s documentation, `setPersistence` method is not supported in `React Native`, link is mentioned below.

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/auth/reference/auth#Unsupported-Methods

You can check this answer if this may help you,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46143694/11758792