# onAuthStateChanged return User=null when Reload/Refresh Page, firebase React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have problem in firebase authentication - React Native.
using `OnAuthStateChanged`

the login process was successfully executed. but when page is refreshed/reloaded, in debugger it shows value `user = 'null'`,
even though I'm logged in.

```
import {onAuthStateChanged} from 'firebase/auth';
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {auth} from '../../utils/firebase';

export default function GetStarted({navigation}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
      console.log('user :', user);
      if (user) {
        navigation.replace('MainApp');
      } else {
        //
      }
    });
  }, [navigation]);
```

when Logged In ----
[Debugger: Loggin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlySY.png)

When Reload/Refresh Page ---
[Debugger: Reload/Refresh Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AtwQ.png)

using React Native V0.71, Firebase V9
can anyone help me to solve this?, i really appreciate the help

Comment: Which version of firebase you are using? I can see from your import its not the latest firebase sdk available for react-native

Comment: The version of firebase i'm using is the latest version 9.16.0 (SDK Javascript), does it have any effect with that?...  but SignIn and login are successful

Comment: yes I encounter the exact same issue

Answer (score 3):

react native needs to use AsyncStorage as persistence, change your 'auth' to initializeAuth

1. install AsyncStorage

   ```
   npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
   ```
2. import these

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence} from 
'firebase/auth/react-native';

...

const Auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)
})
```

3. then restart

Comment: I just changed
`const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);` to 

`const auth = initializeAuth(firebaseApp, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
})`

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be running on a platform where the Firebase SDK doesn't automatically persist user data. Have a look at the documentation on [authentication state persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence) to find your options.

Comment: thanks for the advice @FrankvanPuffelen, I've read the documentation..

I have followed according to the documentation, after I tried it turned out to be an error like this..

`@firebase/auth: Auth (9.16.0): INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition`. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u35ZcwicxUozUzzB336lY9gidhjmF36W/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I you are using react-navigation v6 I strongly suggest you use the logic below

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { onAuthStateChanged, getAuth } from "firebase/auth/react-native";
import app from "../firebase-initialization";
import AuthNavigator from "./auth-navigator";
import AppNavigator from "./app-navigator";
import SplashScreen from "./splash-screen";

const auth = getAuth(app); // where app is the app you initialized with firebase

export default function Navigation() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setLoading(true);
      if (user) {
        setAuthState(true);
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        setAuthState(false);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
  return loading ? <SplashScreen/> : <NavigationContainer>{authState ? 
   <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}</NavigationContainer>;
   }
```

you should never user navigation.replace('MainApp') to manually navigate between stacks on auth state changes. Simply put here we're displaying a splash screen until the onAuthStateChanged finishes running. if finished we check if the user is logged in. if yes authState is true else false. and we display MainApp or authStack accordingly.

**Edit**
I noticed firebase uses AsyncStorage from react native for storing user's session (Whether it is a secure way to store it I don't think so ) so you may run into a warning saying that AsyncStorage must be imported from @react-native-async-storage/async-storage.